# Board of Important Numbers

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, story, number-sequence

I was visiting my cousin, a mystery writer and lover of puzzles, when I noticed this list of numbers on her white board.

> 13,814,070
> 26,818,110
> 86,811,060
> 18,819,190
> 10,914,190
> 33,915,010
> 36,912,211
> 40,025,060

"Is this part of a new puzzle you've been working on?" I asked.

She responded, "Well, I don't know if I'm going to use it yet, but yes. The answer would be the next number in the list."

Never able to solve her puzzles, I just asked what the next number was.

To my surprise, she replied, "I haven't figured that out yet."

But when I asked her more about, she chuckled and wouldn't tell me anymore. She just said it was easy enough and I'd figure it out eventually. It's been a long time and I haven't figured it out.

What number comes next?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my first time using this site so bear with me if I don't know what I'm doing. Answered this but it was deleted? So I'll try again.

> The numbers are the dates of U.S. presidents' deaths in reverse, for the 5th president (07/04/1831), 10th president, 15th, etc.  The missing # is the date of the 45th president's death.  But he (Trump) is still alive so my proposed answer is that the puzzle has no answer (yet).  Guess I'll figure it out eventually.   Fun puzzle!

Comment: Great solve, and nice puzzle! (You did post a previous answer which was deleted, but in that post you didn't actually say what the solution is - it just seemed like an off-topic comment, hence the deletion.)

Comment: Great job and welcome!